# How can I get an offline PDF manual of my MikroTik router when only HTML manuals are provided?

Tags: router, pdf, mikrotik

https://mikrotik.com/product/hex_s#fndtn-downloads

No PDFs. Only HTML hyperlinks going to HTML pages hosted on their servers.

I want to save down PDF for the manuals for my new router, just like I do for all my hardware, so I don't need a working Internet connection to understand them.

My old Mikrotik router has PDFs.

Comment: "Why have they stopped providing PDFs?" - It is impossible for us to answer this question.  If you want to know the reason a PDF manual isn't available then you should contact Mikrotik directly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Don't be ridiculous. There is nothing unclear about what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the [Mikrotik website you linked](https://mikrotik.com/product/hex_s#fndtn-downloads), scroll down a bit and open the User Manual:

[image]

On the new page press the three dots in the upper right and click "Export to PDF":

[image]

Comment: The product "user manual" has little info. One suspects the poster is wanting the RouterOS manual instead. The "Export to PDF" feature just gives a PDF download of the single displayed webpage. One would have to do that hundreds of times to get the entire RouterOS manual, in a hideous format.

Comment: That was not clear to me from the question. But if its the routerOS one is looking for there are a few pdf reference manuals online found by the query "routerOS manual pdf". Is that what you're looking for?